# Adding wkt.csv file to QGIS 3 project using script

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, csv, well-known-text

I have written a plugin using the  Plugin_Builder tool. It takes a CSV, rearranges it and adds a column  of WKT coordinates in the style LINESTRING(x1 y1,x2 y2). It then writes it as a new .csv.
This works fine.  I can then manually import it as 'delimited text' and it loads as a normal visible, interrogatable layer.
What I am trying to do is get the script to load the CSV into QGIS directly after creating the file.
After writing the CSV to my chosen location (out_filename), I have added the following:

```
            ##adding the file to QGIS
            uri='out_filename?&wktField=%s'%("wkt")   
            #uri ='file:///C://Users//Desktop//test2.csv?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:2154&wktField=%s' % (",", "WKT")
            layer = self.iface.addVectorLayer(uri, "my_layer", "delimitedtext")
            #QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer,out_filename + '.shp', 'CP1250', None, 'ESRI Shapefile')
            #QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

The # lines are me trying experiments, none of which work. I wasn't sure if it was just not finding the file, hence the explicit name. A layer is loaded but with no contents. The QGIS error message is:

```
2022-06-04T14:09:44     WARNING    Errors in file C://Users//Desktop//test2.csv
2022-06-04T14:09:44     WARNING    File cannot be opened or delimiter parameters are not valid
```

The layer that is created has a red warning icon next to the name. If I click it and redirect it to the file location, it opens as expected.

The headers and first two rows look like:

```
Name,ID,Seq,Heading,Start time,End time,SOL Fix,EOL Fix,Wind,Waves,Format,Type,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,Nav,USBL,Comments,Status,Length,Project,Client,Area,Contractor,Vessel,Datum,EPSG,WKT
EQ22307-01001-04,1,,22.355,,,,,,,Prime,Analogue,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-, ,Virgin,8.644,,,,,,ED50 - UTM 29N/-9E,,"LINESTRING(525182.750 6756568.136,528470.372 6764562.356)"
EQ22307-01005-08,2,,22.355,,,,,,,Prime,Analogue,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-, ,Virgin,8.644,,,,,,ED50 - UTM 29N/-9E,,"LINESTRING(525205.871 6756558.628,528493.493 6764552.848)"
```

Comment: do you need `'` around your delimiter in the url?

Comment: if you mean uri='out_filename?&wktField=%s'%('wkt')  instead of ("wkt"), I have just tried and got the same error.  I have aslo tried with WKT  insted of wkt to match the capitalisation on my CSV file - same error.

Comment: If I understand your workflow correctly, you read a csv into QGIS, calculate some geographical properties from the csv-file, converts this to WKT, saves as a csv and then re-reads it into QGIS to display it. Could it be possible to in stead just read the initial csv, calculate the geometry and display it and then, if needed, be able to save the layer afterwards?

Comment: @MortenSickel that is something I'm looking at as an alternative.  I have been keeping it as a .CSV (as a WatchFile) because it is easier for me to do a lot of the other things I do with it (outside QGIS) if it stays as an Excel interactable file. If I had to export it from QGIS every time I need to do QGIS-external work then it becomes just as slow as importing the .CSV each time I make a change.

Comment: @WillH, Then it makes sense,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After learning how to import a X/Y point pairs, I rejigged the code to get it to work for WKT.CSV.  I think my problem above was primarily the file path/uri.
This code now works:

```
    uri="file:///"+out_filename+"?delimiter={}&wktField={}".format(",","WKT")
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, project+"_QC", "delimitedtext")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
    my_crs=QgsProject.instance().crs().authid()
    vlayer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(my_crs))
```